# Purchasing Order: An Analysis on A ($\textrm{C++}$)-Approached Recurrence Relation

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

Suppose that we have $n$ dollars and that each day we buy either tape at a dollar, paper at a dollar, pens at two dollars, pencils at two dollars, or binders at three dollars. If $R_n$ is the number of ways of spending all the money, derive a recurrence relations for the sequence $R_1$, $R_2$, $\dots$

---

Just as an aside, for anybody here who has some experience with $\textrm C{+}{+}$ perhaps it would be enlightening to teach this as a recursive algorithm, as, for example with this algorithm I made for [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454326/check-n-bit-strings-containing-a-pattern/454379#454379):

```
int S( int n ){

if( n == 0 )
    return 1;
if( n == 1 )
    return 2;
if( n == 2 )
    return 4;
if( n == 3 )
    return 7;
return 2*S( n - 2 ) + S( n - 1 );

}
```

Comment: I have no idea what the C++ code has to do with the math involved, but whatever the case, your code has a really bad performance. In fact, the result will be calculated as sum of exponentially many elements, while even a simple non-recursive loop would take linear time. There are recursive functions that would calculate this fast, but those do not look like this (e.g. google "tail recursion fibonacci"). Sorry for the harsh words, but I found it hard to put it another way. If you want to deal with C++ code, maybe try asking about it at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: BTW, you have too many semicolons after `if( n == 3)`.

Comment: Ha ha ha, yes...

Answer (score 1):

There are exactly $3$ exhaustive and mutually exclusive ways to make your first purchase.

**Case 1:** Suppose you spend $1$ dollar by buying either the tape or paper first. This can be done in $2$ ways. After doing this, there are $R_{n-1}$ ways to spend the remaining $n-1$ dollars.

**Case 2:** Suppose you spend $2$ dollars by buying either the pens or pencils first. This can be done in $2$ ways. After doing this, there are $R_{n-2}$ ways to spend the remaining $n-2$ dollars.

**Case 3:** Suppose you spend $3$ dollars by buying the binders first. This can be done in $1$ way. After doing this, there are $R_{n-3}$ ways to spend the remaining $n-3$ dollars.

Putting everything together (and after working out some base cases), we obtain:
$$ R_n=\begin{cases}
2 & \text{if }n=1 \\
6 & \text{if }n=2 \\
21 & \text{if }n=3 \\
2R_{n-1}+2R_{n-2}+R_{n-3} & \text{if }n\geq4 \\
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

The mathematician's way is to use generating functions: $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty R_iz^i = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (2z+2z^2+z^3)^k =\frac{1}{1-2z-2z^2-z^3}$$ Unfortunately, the roots of $1-2z-2z^2-z^3$ are non-trivial, but the sequence $R_n\sim cr^n$ where $c$ is a some constant and $r\approx 2.8312$ is the real root of $x^3-2x^2-2x-1$. (It's actually stronger than this - more like $|R_n-cr^n|\to 0$ since the complex roots are of modulus less than $1$.)

You also get from this equation that $R_{n+3} = 2R_{n+2}+2R_{n+1}+R_n$, which is sort of obvious.